# IntelliJ TestNG customsuite do not copy parameters

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, testng, intellij-plugin

I have a issue with the TestNG plugin in IntelliJ. I run my tests by using a `testng.xml`. The I define parameters on the suite and test level.

If I want to run only one test from IntelliJ by selecting it and run as debug, IntelliJ copies the test into a temporary testng.xml like this one:

```
/Users/robert/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2016.1/temp-testng-customsuite.xml
```

The problem is, the suite has no parameters defined in my `testng.xml` file. So TestNG ignores the test because it misses the parameters that doesn't match to the test `@Parameters` declaration.

How to run a single TestNG test in IntelliJ with using of parametrized `testng.xml`?

Best regards
Robert

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

On IntelliJ, go to `Run > Edit Configurations > Select tab Configuration > Select tab Parameters`.

There, add the desired parameters.